# How do Substitution levels in Champions of Valor work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, forgotten-realms

As you may know, the substitution levels, as introduced in Champions of Valor are, as quoted:

> Substitution levels are levels of a given class that you take to gain certain benefits instead of the level benefits associated with the standard class. Selecting a substitution level is not the same as multiclassing; you remain in the class for which the substitution level was taken. The class features of the substitution level simply replace those of the normal level.

My question is what happens to the level-based benefits of an ability that has not been replaced at the substitution level? Spellcasting is explicitly described as "unless stated" spellcasting is increased. I'm referring to other abilities, let me give an example to elaborate:

-- **Paladin 6** vs **Paladin 4/Crescent Moon Knight 2** (who has taken both 4th and 6th levels)

How much does *Lay on Hands* heal for the 2nd character, with a Cha score 12?

6 or 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If the ability was not replaced or otherwise affected by a substitution level, it works the same way as if the substitution level was not taken.**

Please note that **Paladin4/Crescent Moon Knight 2** is actually a **Paladin 6** with a different set of class features.

Namely, the first substitution level replaces Paladin's 4th level and trades *turn undead* class feature for *favored enemy*, whereas second substitution level replaces Paladin's 6th level and changes his *remove disease* ability.

Nothing in these substitution levels affect Paladin's *lay on hands* ability, so the second character in question heals as much as the first, 6 hp.